# JSON array data is not getting displayed while executing each loop

Tags: jquery, json

Here is my JSON array:

```
[
  {
    "EmployeeAttachment": {
      "id": "1",
      "client_id": "D-3043065515",
      "emp_id": "E0002",
      "forward_by": null,
      "datetime": "2015-07-03 00:20:13"
    }
  },
  {
    "Employee": {
      "id": "4",
      "emp_id": "E0004",
      "first_name": "emp",
      "middle_name": null,
      "last_name": "test",
      "gender": "F",
      "dob": "1958-07-24",
      "status": "active",
      "full_name": "emp test"
    },
    "EmployeeHistory": {
      "id": "2",
      "emp_id": "E0004",
      "department_id": "1",
      "designation_id": "4",
      "devision_id": "1",
      "grade_id": "1",
      "joining_date": "2015-07-08",
      "resign_date": null,
      "basic_salary": "6.00",
      "reporting_to": "E0002",
      "reporting_office": "1",
      "leave_approval_authority": "0",
      "sales_promotion_approval_authority": "0",
      "sales_promotion_limit": "0.00",
      "field_personnel": "1",
      "field_service": "1",
      "sales_manager": "0",
      "work_location": "tezpur"
    }
  }
]
```

and my `each` loop is as follows:

```
$.each(resp,function(indx,obj){ 
  emp_id_att= obj.EmployeeAttachment.emp_id;alert(emp_id_att);
  emp_id=obj.EmployeeHistory.work_location;alert(emp_id);
});
```

`emp_id` is not getting displayed when the loop is executed.

Comment: I have improved the formatting of your JSON array to make it easily readable. A lengthy single line of code/data with scrollbars is difficult to read. I have also reworded the title to improve grammar.

Answer (score 0):

You should not declare global variables. Create local variables using `var` keyword.

Your problem is the two objects in the array aren't the same type. First item has `EmployeeAttachment` only and the second item has `Employee` and `EmployeeHistory`.

```
$.each(resp,function(indx,obj){

  if (obj.EmployeeAttachment) { // CHECK before you use

    // create local variables instead of global
    var emp_id_att = obj.EmployeeAttachment.emp_id;
    alert(emp_id_att);

  }

  if (obj.EmployeeHistory) { // CHECK before you use

    var emp_id = obj.EmployeeHistory.work_location;
    alert(emp_id);

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON array is not valid in that it doesn't contain objects of the same type/structure. So iterating it might be difficult. You're expecting EmployeeAttachment and EmployeeHistory to be a member of the same top-level object, but they are not.

Check out your JSON using this invaluable tool for more clarity: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Paste then click Format in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate using such json as the object key is different for each object. It will work only for one object at a time and will throw undefined for the other:
Try using **if** conditions in your **for loop**

```
$.each(resp,function(indx,obj){ 

   if (obj.EmployeeAttachment){
     emp_id_att= obj.EmployeeAttachment.emp_id;
     alert(emp_id_att);
   }  

   if(obj.EmployeeHistory){
     emp_id=obj.EmployeeHistory.work_location;
     alert(emp_id);
   }
});
```

Also wanted to mention that if you do not provide **var** the variable will be treated as a global variable.